# Gradle build condition

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to make build configuration of multimodule project.
[image]
My goal is to have configuration, which will build war-file and deploy it to Tomcat.
My project contains four subprojects. There are:

- api-common
- api-school
- api-spo
- api-odo

I'd like to have war with all of modules or just some of them (api-common must always be in war)

I've main build.gradle where I configure cargo plugin

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'

allprojects{
    apply plugin: 'java'
    group = 'ru.dnevnik.enrollment'
    version = '2.0'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.1'
    }
}

cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat7x'

    deployable {
        context = 'api'
        file = file('enrollment-api\\build\\libs\\enrollment-api-1.0.war') //todo: bad practice
    }
}
```

Enrollment-api project has build.gradle file as

```
apply plugin: 'war'

configurations {
    full
    odo
    spo
    school
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':enrollment-api-common')
    odo project(':enrollment-api-odo')
    school project(':enrollment-api-school')
    spo project(':enrollment-api-spo')

}
```

I don't understand how to use configurations to run for example

```
gradle cargoDeployRemote {someFlag}
```

to achive my goal